# Steam says I do not have enough disk space available to install a game, even though I have plenty. How do I solve this?

Tags: steam, linux, wine

When I try to install Bioshock Infinite (for example), on the game installation page, it says that I have 12846MB available, but if I look at my Steam library folders through Settings > Downloads > Steam Library Folders, it says that I have 13.48GB of space remaining. How do I correct this disparity in remaining space being reported?

I have Steam installed under the latest version of wine, on the latest version of Manjaro Linux (amd_64).

Comment: [Bioshock Infinite has a minimum requirement of 20GB of disk space.](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/BioShock_Infinite_Technical_Information) so I'm confused as to why you say ~13gb is plenty?

Comment: @AndyJ You know what, that's a good question. My brain was all out of whack yesterday, with MB not translating around properly in my head.

Comment: That's understandable. I'd be lying if I said I never got mixed up when converting between KB/MB/GB/etc in my head.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Steam probably displays in mebibytes (1024 kibibytes per mebibyte) and your file manager in megabytes (1000 kilobytes per megabyte).

Converting 12846MiBs to MBs give us 13470MBs, which is just a bit less than the space you have available, but with cache usage and stuff like that, the storage you have free might fluctuate, causing steam to think that you can't install the game.

The solution is to clear up your drive a bit (and as you're on manjaro, try out `pacman -Sc`, which will allow you to clear old versions of the packages you have installed).

Comment: You know what, that's proabably the issue. I'll get around to allocating more space to my Linux partition then.

Comment: You're three degrees off in your unit conversions...

Comment: @JohnDvorak oops, my bad. Someone fixed them now.

Comment: Have you switched the numbers? It should always be `x/MB > x/MiB` for any positive `x`.